# Passing POST variables from jQuery to PHP, want to update div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass the form value "New Value" from jQuery to a PHP script, and then update the "to_change" div from "Old value" to "New value". It seemed like the AJAX call succeeded, but the POST variables are not being sent to the PHP script, and when I use getJSON, I do not succeed. How could I resolve this issue?

Javascript/HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form_tmin").submit(function(event) {
                    var values = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "parameters_form2.php",
                        data: values,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){
                                     $.getJSON("parameters_form2.php", function(tmin) {
                                         document.getElementById("to_change").innerHTML = tmin[1];
                                     });
                                 }
                    });
                        return false;
                });         
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="to_change">Old value</div>
            <form id="form_tmin" name="form_tmin">
                <input type="hidden" id="tmin_value" name="tmin_value" value="New value">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if ($_POST["tmin_value"]) {
    $tmin[1] = $_REQUEST["tmin_value"];
}
else {
    $tmin[1] = "FAILURE";
}
echo json_encode($tmin);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have json response in data just set this data in where ever you want to display. you don not need `$.getJSON` again.

try like this:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form_tmin").submit(function(event) {
                    var values = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "parameters_form2.php",
                        data: values,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){

                             document.getElementById("to_change").innerHTML = data[1];

                           }
                    });
                        return false;
                });         
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the response of query, no need to use `$.getJson` again

Instead just use:

```
success: function(data){
    $("to_change").html(data[1]);
}
```